# Generate stateful function pointer for FFI testing

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I want to generate stateful functions (C signature `T f()`) with QuickCheck as arguments for foreign functions. Preferably I also want to make them (or their inner `s->(T,s)`) showable.

I know that for stateless functions I can write something like

```
type Compare = CInt -> CInt -> CBool
foreign import ccall "wrapper"
  mkCompare :: Compare -> IO (FunPtr Compare)
```

but I got stuck trying this approach for the stateful functions, as I don't see how I can translate the monad hiding the state in Haskell to the function hiding the state in C.

**Example of a stateful function f**

```
static int i = 0;

int f() {
    return i++;
}
```

In Haskell I would represent this function as `State (\s -> (s,s+1))`.

**What does QuickCheck have to do with it?**

If I have a C function that takes a stateful function as argument, e.g.

```
int twice(int (*f)()) {
    f();
    return f();
}
```

then I can test the function with QuickCheck, where QuickCheck can generate different implementations for `f`, which would usually look similar to

```
prop_total (Fun f) xs = total $ g f xs
```

but these generated functions are stateless, not stateful like the example C function above.

Comment: Perhaps somebody else can help you, but I'm not understanding what you are asking. First of all are you talking about C or C++? What is a "stateful function object" (is it a function or a C++ object)? What does QuickCheck have to do with it? Can you show a usage example in C code (not C++)?

Comment: @Noughtmare Thanks for telling me where my question was unclear. I've edited it to eliminate mentions of C++, which is irrelevant here, and answered your other questions. If there's anything else unclear, please let me know!

Comment: Not an FFI expert... does `type Compare = CInt -> CInt -> IO CBool` get you where you need to go? Then you can write `whatever :: IORef Whatever -> Compare` to get a stateful `Compare`, and QuickCheck can generate a `Whatever -> CInt -> CInt -> (Whatever, CBool)` that you can wrap into a `IORef Whatever -> Compare`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Hmm, maybe. I'll have to experiment with this a bit, as I face some difficulties with the IO type not being accepted as parameter type in the foreign declaration, and with IORef not having a QuickCheck instance. I'll let you know if I make any progress. If you could write up an answer with executable code, that would also be great.

Comment: @JohannesRiecken About the FFI part I'm not super sure. But on the QuickCheck bit: my comment proposes that you have QuickCheck generate a `Whatever -> CInt -> CInt -> (Whatever, CBool)`, which does not mention `IORef`; then, after it's generated, you can wrap it up to do something to an `IORef` instead of having explicit state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Wagner's suggestion in the comments, I could figure it out. The Show instance comes for free. Here's a minimal example that I ran with

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libstateful.dylib stateful.c && ghc -L. Stateful.hs -lstateful && ./Stateful
```

As expected it will output a distribution of about 50% of 1 (True) and 50% of 0 (False).

**Stateful.hs**

```
import Data.IORef
import Foreign.C
import Foreign.Ptr
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Test.QuickCheck

instance CoArbitrary CInt where
  coarbitrary = coarbitraryIntegral

instance Arbitrary CBool where
  arbitrary = chooseEnum (0,1)
  shrink 1 = [0]
  shrink 0 = []

instance Function CInt where
  function = functionIntegral

type Generator = IO CBool

foreign import ccall "wrapper" mkGenerator :: Generator -> IO (FunPtr Generator)

foreign import ccall "changes" changes :: FunPtr Generator -> IO CBool

type StateFn = CInt -> (CBool,CInt)

stateFnToIORef :: StateFn -> IORef CInt -> IO CBool
stateFnToIORef f s_ref = do
    s <- readIORef s_ref
    let (a,s') = f s
    writeIORef s_ref s'
    pure a

prop_changes :: Fun CInt (CBool,CInt) -> Property
prop_changes (Fn f) = unsafePerformIO (do
    x_ref <- newIORef 0
    f' <- mkGenerator $ stateFnToIORef f x_ref
    res <- changes f'
    pure $ collect res (total res))

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_changes
```

**stateful.c**

```c
_Bool changes(_Bool (*f)()) {
    _Bool x = f();
    _Bool y = f();
    return x != y;
}
```